# Rendering Vue slot elements in template loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, swiper.js

I am trying to pass the HTML for slides into a component using slots then render them as another component

```
// carousel.blade.php
<my-carousel>
<template v-slot:slides>
    <div>slide 1</div>
    <div>slide 2</div>
</template>
</my-carousel>
```

`MyCarousel` should then take each `<div>` and turn it into a Swiper slide.

I can loop over the elements passed into the slot using `slots.slides()`. My questions is, how do I render the contents of that element inside swiper-slide?

```
// MyCarousel.vue
<script setup>
import { useSlots } from "vue";

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
import 'swiper/css';

const slots = useSlots();

console.log(slots.slides());
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <swiper>
            <swiper-slide v-for="(slide, key) in slots.slides()">
                <!-- render the current slide/slot content -->
            </swiper-slide>
        </swiper>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

I know I could use Swiper directly inside my Blade view but I am trying to avoid this and only convert the slides into `<swiper-slides>` when wrapped in the Vue component. The rest of the time it will use the plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Typical, after searching for ages I find the solution just after posting my question. It’s very simple too.

Each `slide` in the loop can be rendered as a dynamic `<component>`

```
<script setup>
import { useSlots } from "vue";

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
import 'swiper/css';

const slots = useSlots();

console.log(slots.slides());
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <swiper>
            <swiper-slide v-for="(slide, key) in slots.slides()" v-bind="props">
                <component :is="slide" />
            </swiper-slide>
        </swiper>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```